# Disable repeating email sign in error notification

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, imap, stock-email-app

When there are problems with IMAP server that I'm using, email app makes a notification every few seconds or minutes (inbox check frequency is set to `every hour`):

`Couldn't sign in` which leads to another message: `The username or password for foo@example.com is incorrect. Update them now?`.

There is nothing wrong with my password, it's just temporary problem with server.
How can I disable such notifications while keeping new mail notifications ?

All I can see in options is a single `Email notifications` checkbox.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could let us know which (device, Android version, and) mail app you are using. Keep in mind that different devices/Android versions/ROMs use different "default apps", and the settings might be different between them. Thank you!

Comment: See tags (4.0.3, stock email app). Device is ZTE Blade III.

Comment: I have this same problem on CM 10.2 on a Galaxy S3. I really just want to silence this notification for a particular account that misbehaves frequently.